# Understanding Continuity Proof: $y = \sin x$

Tags: calculus, continuity, proof-explanation

[image]

I do not understand the following:

- I understand that taking the lim of y for delta x --> 0 is the definition of continuity of a function. Though, I am confused why the author is changing the form of the equation before taking the lim?
- Also I do not see the identities the author is using that allows for the first modification of y (2sin(deltax)/2 ... step)

Could someone help explain this?

Comment: For the first point: what definition of continuity in a point have you got? For the second point, look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities (second table, sum-to-product).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. We don't know that $\sin$ is continuous, but we know the limit $\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$ at 0. Hence the transformation to use this fact.
2. $\sin\alpha -\sin\beta=2\sin((\alpha-\beta)/2)\cos((\alpha+\beta)/2)$.

Comment: So to clarify, the author is modifying the limit to recognizable continuous forms and then solving to equal 0? I am assuming that the assumption -1<= cosx <= 1 allows the delta x at the end to make the whole thing 0?

Answer (score 1):

They use the high-school factorisation formula:
$$\sin p-\sin q=2\sin\frac{p-q}2\cos\frac{p+q}2,$$
which is deduced fom the linearisation formula
$$2\sin b\cos a=\sin(a+b)-\sin(a-b).$$